# How to copy purchase order value to account.invoice in odoo11

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I have created a custom field in the purchase order and another in account.invoice with the same name budget_id, when I create a purchase order and create a bill from this order I would like to copy the value of budget_id in the purchase order to the budget_id in the bill.

I have overridden the smart button method "action_view_invoice" in purchase.order and added my code but nothing happen. Are there other ways to do that?

Thanks in advance!

my code
@api.multi
def action_view_invoice(self):

```
        action = self.env.ref('account.action_invoice_tree2')
        result = action.read()[0]

        result['context'] = {'type': 'in_invoice', 'default_purchase_id': self.id}

        if not self.invoice_ids:
            # Choose a default account journal in the same currency in case a new invoice is created
            journal_domain = [
                ('type', '=', 'purchase'),
                ('company_id', '=', self.company_id.id),
                ('currency_id', '=', self.currency_id.id),
            ]
            default_journal_id = self.env['account.journal'].search(journal_domain, limit=1)
            if default_journal_id:
                result['context']['default_journal_id'] = default_journal_id.id
        else:
            # Use the same account journal than a previous invoice
            result['context']['default_journal_id'] = self.invoice_ids[0].journal_id.id

        # choose the view_mode accordingly
        if len(self.invoice_ids) != 1:
            result['domain'] = "[('id', 'in', " + str(self.invoice_ids.ids) + ")]"
        elif len(self.invoice_ids) == 1:
            res = self.env.ref('account.invoice_supplier_form', False)
            result['views'] = [(res and res.id or False, 'form')]
            result['res_id'] = self.invoice_ids.id
        result['context']['default_origin'] = self.name
        result['context']['default_reference'] = self.partner_ref
        result['context']['default_budget_id'] = self.budget_id.id # my code here

        return result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `account.invoice` object has the field `purchase_id` which is a link with `purchase.order`.
So in the account.invoice you can get any of the way(like in the vendor bill creation best approch) the **purchase order** `budget_id` field value into **account.invoice** `budget_id` field.

Code link - [Purchase link In Invoice](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/purchase/models/account_invoice.py#L11)

Comment: so I have to add purchase_id  to account.invoice  cuz it's not defined in the model in my addons

Comment: I actually don't like the answer, because where is the answer here? When will `account.invoice.purchase_id` be set? Just try it out, try to find one single supplier invoice in default Odoo with `purchase_id` set to it. You won't find one, which leads to the question, how is the hint to `purchase_id` helping others, who will read this answer? I actually know what's behind that field, and maybe the questioner is knowing it now, too. But that's not the reason why StackOverflow was made. Please get into more detail in your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Oh and if i understand the asking person correctly (his/her two comments), than your answer wasn't helpful the way you've probably wanted it to :-O